# Battery and volume icons not showing, greyed out in options

Tags: windows-7

I just started my laptop, running on battery, and these two icons aren't showing up.

In the settings, they're greyed out.

Screenshot:

[image]

There's probably a registry key controlling this, but I don't know which one that is. Plus, I don't know what caused this.

Comment: My battery power expired last evening while I was working on my laptop, so recharged it. When I put my computer on this morning the battery power icon has re-appeared. I checked in the Taskbar and Start Menu properties box and the box next to 'Power' which was greyed out yesterday, is now checked. Go figure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ref: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19085-system-icons-enable-disable.html
(I've reformatted)

1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor.
2. In the left pane, click on an expand User Configuration, Administrative Templates, and Start Menu and Taskbar.
3. For the Volume Icon - In the right pane, right click on Remove the volume control icon and click on Edit. Select Disabled or Not Configured and click on OK.
4. For the Power (battery) Icon - In the right pane, right click on Remove the battery meter and click on Edit. Select Disabled or Not Configured and click on OK.
5. When done, close the Local Group Policy Editor.
6. Log off and log on, or restart the computer to fully apply.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. When going to the editor, both policies were already set to "Not Configured". So kinda weird still that this would happen.

Answer (score 1):

For me, something had set the registry entry *HideSCAVolume* under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

I fixed it by removing this entry and restarting Windows Explorer.

[Fix for When Volume Icon is Missing and Grayed Out in Windows](//howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fix-for-when-clock-volume-power-or-network-icons-are-missing-and-grayed-out-in-windows-vista)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your power management settings have been turned off, so...

1. Click start, in the search bar type `msconfig` and press Enter.
2. Select the Startup tab and scroll down until you see power management or anything similar - look for your computer's manufacture name in the manufacturer tab. Tick it and restart your computer.